# How to user relative colors with SASS?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I want to use relative colors in my project made with Nuxt.

When I add this line of code:

```
  background-color: rgb(from var(--color) r g b / .5);
```

SASS throws this error:
SassError: Only 3 elements allowed, but 5 were passed.

Is there any way to bypass it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same case and issue, and a workaround I found was to use the unquote-function of sass.

```css
$color: 'rgb(from var(--color) r g b / .5'
background-color: unquote($color);
```

An alternative setup was to add a CSS file to my Angular project, but this was a bit more clean.

I'm wondering though when relative css colors will be fully implemented in SASS. I did find this related issue: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/3673.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `rgba` (not `rgb`) like this:

```
background-color: rgba(var(--color), 0.5);
```

---

**EDIT**

```
background-color: rgba(var(--color), 0.5) !important;
```

Comment: It doesn't throw error, but for some reason my background color stays same.

Comment: Try to add `!important`. Let me know what happens.